# Android Application communicating with GWT Application

Tags: java, android, http, gwt, client-server

I am developing a mobile application for Android.  The application will act as a front-end for another GWT-application I have running on appspot.com.  To communicate between the two, I need to send data from the client (Android Applcation) to the server (GWT-application), which must then be processed and data sent back to the client.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?  By "best" I mean simple enough for me to understand and implement, but also in line with good practice.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, as I am very new to GWT and can not find a lot of support on the internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Android application development but I guess with "sending data to the GWT application" you mean sending data to your App Engine backend/server.

In the end GWT is just compiled to plain Javascript and runs in the browser. So I don't see how you want to communicate with the GWT part of your app.
However you can send data from your Android app with the backend running on App Engine and eventually the data can be displayed in your GWT application accessed by any browser (mobile, desktop, etc).

For that I think you can either go one of two routes:

1. Create an HTTPRequest from your Android app to the backend using JSON or XML as a data protocol
2. Use RequestFactory (internally uses JSON) in your Android app (There is a special Requestfactory_client.jar package for that. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049351/how-to-use-the-gwt-requestfactory-in-android-syncadapter-always-getting-validat) for more details).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this as soon as my server is running properly!