# RequestFactory validation fails when including Android maps v2 fragment

Tags: android, requestfactory, android-maps-v2

I have successfully used `RequestFactory` for a very long time in my Android app, but now when trying to upgrade to maps v2, when I include

```
<fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

in my XML layout file, I get the error:

> ```
> 01-25 08:08:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(19854):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity{com.xx/com.xx.MyActivity}:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be
> run for the com.xx.client.MyRequestFactory RequestFactory type
> ```

If I remove the fragment code from the layout XML file everything works fine.

How does this fragment affect my RequestFactory validation and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, stumbled on to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049351/how-to-use-the-gwt-requestfactory-in-android-syncadapter-always-getting-validat and it solved the problem, but I don't understand exactly why yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in [How to Use the GWT-RequestFactory in Android SyncAdapter (always getting ValidationTool-Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049351/how-to-use-the-gwt-requestfactory-in-android-syncadapter-always-getting-validat)

if one adds

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(mContext.getClassLoader());
```

before

```
requestFactory = RequestFactorySource.create(factoryClass);
```

the problem is fixed.